# Passing PHP variables with html code to JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm appending a newly published comment to the comment list, which contains PHP variables with html code. I'm doing this through JQuery, and wondering what is the best way to do it. Would we typically use an ajax call?

Thanks. code is as follows:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<button class="reply_button">Comment<button>
```

Then afther a Jquery ajax sumbmission, the PHP file would return the following info as $comment to be passed into Jquery append() function:

```
<div class='comment' id='<?php echo $reply_id=$row->reply_id; ?>'>
<span class="subCommentArrow" id='<?php echo $reply_id=$row->reply_id; ?>'>Comment_ID</span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function()
{
  $('.reply_button').click(function(){
  var reply = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();

      $.ajax({ 
          type:"POST", 
          url: base_url + "interview/reply_upload",
          data:{reply:reply}, 
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data,status){
            if(data.state == 'succ')
            {
              this_a.html('Success');
            $('.reply_button').append('$Comment');
            }
            else
            {
              this_a.html('fail');  
            }
      }
      });

   }); 
});
```

I only know the general flow of passing $comment from php to Jquery, but not sure on the details of how to implement it. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `php` would be inside the `data` variable of the callback. Not `$comment`

Comment: you cant access PHP variable client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$('.reply_button').append('$Comment');
```

to:

```
$('.reply_button').after(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I would have to define what "data" is in the php file? Given the info I need to pass contains php variable and html, what is the best way for me to define that in the php file?

Comment: `data` is whatever result that you've returned from your php file, it's can be json, array, object, string.... so it's really depends on that `data` to handle it inside your `success` function

Comment: Got it. So I would need to write something like this in the php file: data="<div>....$comment </div>, right?

Comment: You need to `echo` in php. Check this basic tutorial on how to use jQuery, PHP and AJAX together: http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html

Answer (score 0):

if your javascript is in your php file, and your php already knows the $comment, you *can* put php in javascript like below, however it's not best practice for organized code. Like this:

```
$('.reply_button').append('<?php echo $Comment; ?>'); // without ajax // only works if your javascript is in a .php file
```

but for a jquery ajax call you would need to parse the response from the ajax call and display the response, which is better.

```
$.post(base_url + "interview/reply_upload", {"reply":reply}, function(result){
    var comment = result; //or result.comment if result is an object
    $('.reply_button').append(comment);
}, "json");
```

$.post is just a shorter function of your $.ajax, but gets to the root of your question. hope i understood right.

Comment: My Jquery is in the html, since guess I'll have to use an ajax call to get "var comment = result". But how should I properly package the "result" (I assume I would need to package the "result" in the php file)

Comment: you "result" from your ajax call will return whatever gets displayed or 'echoed' from your php. so in the php file that your ajax function calls make sure to only echo what you want 'result' to contain. so..if it's just the comment you're trying to get just end your php file with `echo $comment`, if you're echoing an object you have to json_encode it: `$object = array("comment"=>$comment, "comment_owner"=>$comment_owner, "comment_date"=>$comment_date); echo json_encode($object);`

Comment: Thanks. Guess my question now is how to format these php variables together with html code in the php file. I know that I can use json_encode function to do an array, but that's where I'm stopped. Would you mind shedding some light?

Comment: I remember first learning this was confusing, so I'll add another answer to lay it out more.

Comment: Gracias milleu amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way it all works together using ajax. Hopefully this answers your question.

MAIN FILE:

```
<textarea>Hi this is a comment</textarea>
<button class="reply_button">Comment<button>

<script>
    $('.reply_button').click(function(){
        var reply = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();

        $.post("myajax.php", {"reply":reply}, function(result){
            var comment = result.comment; 
            var reply_id = result.reply_id;
            $('.reply_button').after("<p id="+reply_id+">"+comment+"</p>");
        }, "json");

    });

</script>
```

when you click the reply button it will call the ajax function and pass the reply as a POST to your myajax.php file. myajax.php will process it, and echo the json_encoded comment object with whatever you want in it. Then the Ajax callback function will take whatever 'myajax.php' echoed, and store it in 'result', and then you can use the 'result' object and do whatever you want with it. (I used *after* instead of append, to add a paragraph containing the result and the reply_id after the button.)

MYAJAX.PHP

```
$reply = $_POST['reply'];

... insert comment into database...
... get $reply_id from database...

$commentObject = array("comment"=>$reply, "reply_id"=>$reply_id);
echo json_encode($commentObject);
exit; // or end of file, or jus make sure nothing else gets echoed.
```

Hope this gives you a start. If you're doing nested comment threading you'll have to use store the id's of the replys and parent replys and all that stuff, but this is a basic look at a common use of an ajax call.